# How to let a view controller know it should fetch data from the server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to find the right way of notifying a view controller that it should fetch data from the server based on an action of another view controller.

For example - a view controller that **presents** a list of tweets, and a view controller that lets the user **create** a tweet. After the user has created a tweet, the view controller that was responsible for **creating** the tweet is being dismissed and the view controller that is responsible for **presenting** the tweet should now be aware that it should reload it's data from the server in order to present the user with the tweet he just created.

At first, I thought `NSNotificationCenter` is the way to go, but after doing a little research (mainly [this twitter discussion](https://twitter.com/NatashaTheRobot/status/511300117148991489)), I found that it is recommended to remove the notification observer in the `viewDidDisappear` method of the view controller, which in the scenario described above, makes the notification useless because the **presenting** view controller would already remove itself from the observers of the notification by the time it should receive it (because it is being hidden by the '**create** tweet' view controller, thus causing it's `viewDidDisappear` method getting called).

Delegation is also a problem here, because there might be other view controllers that might also be in the need of knowing when a new tweet has been created, in order to update their views / fetching data from the server / etc.

Due to the fact that the described flow is very popular, I figured there must be a *correct* way to let these two view controller communicate in a way that will make sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can remove the observers in dealloc method

Comment: Wouldn't it be wrong usage of NSNotificationCenter? Are there any potential problems that may occur?

Comment: I see nothing criminal unless the business logic.

Comment: you can use KVO, notifications, or delegates; you can chose between for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag in your data/network model.
Let's say you have a `TweetNetworking.swift` file which contains your server requests, you could add a `var needFeedRefresh: BOOL`.

Then it's only a matter of setting it to `true` when you need, and `false` once you've refreshed the feed.
You can then check against that variable in `viewWillAppear`.

Another way to go is to type this variable as an `NSDate` if you need periodical refreshes, and set it to `NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:0)` when you need to force refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If the only obstacle to use `NSNotificationCenter` is the fact, that observer is removed in `viewDidDisapper`, you can move calling `removeObserver` to `deinit`, assuming that your observer is only hidden and not deallocated.

For more information see: [iOS8: Where To Remove Observer for NSNotification in Swift](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios8-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification-in-swift/) (it's a post written by the same author as the tweet discussion you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

You can also add notification listener in presenting view controller when you display the another view controller to compose tweet. Then you remove that listener in the callback; then the listener will be removed asap.

```
func showTweetComposer() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(UIPresentingViewController.tweetComposed(_:)), name: UITweetComposeViewControllerDoneKey, object: nil)
}

func tweetComposed(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:notification.name, object: nil)
}
```